# Trying to get a local MySQL database to work with GAE development server

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Soo, I've decided to toy around a bit with GAE. Most of my previous experience with developing web-applications is with ASP.Net, so this java / eclipse-world is kinda unfamiliar to me.

I read around, and found out that I can configure my project to use a Google Cloud SQL instance when it's deployed at Google, while using a local MySQL database while running locally on my development server.

The problem I ran in to now is that I can simply not press "Ok" in the eclipse dialog for configuring my local MySQL database? Well - I can, but with no result. No error message, no window close, no nothing.

I'm not really sure what I am doing wrong, but was hoping some wiz in here who has more experience than me with GAE have had a similar problem and a solution?

I've attached a picture of my local MySQL configuration:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/U83qm.jpg

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nop.. Gave up and used hardcoded connectionstrings which I change depending on the build configuration :)

Comment: Even with hard-coded connection strings we see this error:  java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")   - Any solution??